# Undefined reference to SDL with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I'm working on a project using the SDL (v1.2.15-7) and CMake (3.2.1). In  the *.h files I added the `#include <SDL.h>` and when I compile it, I have a bunch of errors : undefined reference to SDL_...

I think the mistake comes from the CMakeLists.txt but I really don't know where.

Here's the file content :

```
    CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

    SET( PROJ_NAME      "Project" )
    SET( PROJ_PATH      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )
    SET( PROJ_OUT_PATH  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    SET( PROJ_INCLUDES  "include" )

    FILE( GLOB_RECURSE PROJ_SOURCES src/*cpp test/*cpp doc/*)
    FILE( GLOB_RECURSE PROJ_HEADERS ${PROJ_INCLUDES}/${PROJ_NAME}/*.h )

    PROJECT( ${PROJ_NAME} )

    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")

    FIND_PACKAGE( SDL REQUIRED )

    SET( PROJ_LIBRARIES ${SDL_LIBS} )

    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PROJ_INCLUDES} ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR} )
    ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJ_NAME} ${PROJ_SOURCES} ${PROJ_HEADERS} )
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJ_NAME} ${PROJ_LIBRARIES} )
```

I also tried `#include SDL/SDL.h`

Comment: You don't need to add all your headers. Usually they are relative to your targets and will be found automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SDL_LIBRARY` instead of `SDL_LIBS`

Comment: Thanks... I feel so stupid, Next time I'll look more carefully

Comment: @Kruncho: with `make VERBOSE=ON` you would have seen that the libraries are not passed. Next time :-)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is coming from the linker, in which case it means you're not linking against the SDL libraries.

The CMake documentation specifies that the `FindSDL` module defines a variable named `SDL_LIBRARY`, but you're using `SDL_LIBS`. So, `SET(PROJ_LIBRARIES ${SDL_LIBRARY})` instead.

When using a standard module for finding a package, try browsing the documentation first to take a look at the variables it defines. The names aren't always standard.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to link your target to `SDL_LIBRARIES` in the last line of your CMakeLists.txt.

The linker produces the error, so it is unrelated to your includes.

Comment: No I didn't forgot, it's include in the `SET( PROJ_LIBRARIES ${SDL_LIBS} )`. But I tried it anyway and it didn't works

Comment: He's referring to the fact that you misspelled the variable's name. `SDL_LIBS` isn't the same variable as `SDL_LIBRARIES`. In the first case, CMake simply evaluates it to the empty string, hence you end up linking against no library at all.